# Need to get data by its status, but the data is redundant

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table that record all of the transaction, whether is success or fail. When a transaction is failed because of some reasons, other division can re-push the transaction so it will recorded in the same table. Below is the example of data in my table

```
id  | transaction_code | order_code | create_time | status  |
1   |      TR001       |   OC001    |  2019-04-16 |  Fail   |
2   |      TR001       |   OC001    |  2019-04-18 | Success |
```

When an order got re-pushed, its recorded with a new 'create_time'. This transaction is categorized as success.

The problem is when i need to create a report to get all the failed transaction. This transaction is generated from my query (obviously) because i use

```
WHERE status = 'Fail'
```

Another problem is, I'm not the creator of this db schema and my access is limited (I only can use SELECT operation)

Is there any way to solve my problem only with a query?

Comment: It's a fail if there is no success for the same transaction_code,order_code? And can you have a fail after a success?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, its a fail if there is no sucess transaction even after re-push, and no you cant have a fail after a transaction is succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` to find all failed transactions that do not have a success status:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE status = 'fail'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.transaction_code = t.trasaction_code
    AND x.order_code = t.order_code -- not sure if it is required
    AND x.status = 'success'
)
```

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you so much. I need to learn about NOT EXIST function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this, I suggest you try them all and see which is optimal for you

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(
id  int, transaction_code varchar(10), order_code varchar(10), create_time date, status varchar(10));
insert into t values 
(1        ,  'TR001'          , 'OC001'     ,  '2019-04-16' ,   'Fail'),
(2        ,  'TR001'          , 'OC001'     ,  '2019-04-18' ,   'Success'),
(3        ,  'TR002'          , 'OC001'     ,  '2019-04-16' ,   'Fail'),
(4        ,  'TR003'          , 'OC001'     ,  '2019-04-16' ,   'success');

select t.*
from t
left join t t1 on t1.transaction_code = t.transaction_code and t1.status = 'Success'
where t1.status is null;


select * 
from t 
where status = 'FAIL' and 
        not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.transaction_code = t.transaction_code and status = 'Success');

select * 
from t
where t.transaction_Code not in(
select transaction_code from t t1 
where t1.transaction_code = t.transaction_code and status = 'Success'
);

+------+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+
| id   | transaction_code | order_code | create_time | status |
+------+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+
|    3 | TR002            | OC001      | 2019-04-16  | Fail   |
+------+------------------+------------+-------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i'll use it for future references